# Github remote error problem when pushing changes

Tags: git, github, repository

I am trying to push changes to my github repo, but getting an error:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: xxxx
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/data1.csv is 318.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File data/data2.csv is 269.45 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/fbagirov/myrepo
```

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Whatever I do, I can not get it to push: 
 - I have a .gitignore those two files that are over 100MB; when it didn't work, I included the entire data folder into .gitignore:

```
data/data1.csv
data/data2.csv
data/
```

- I tried cleaning the files from the cache:

  git rm -- data1.csv
- I restarted the laptop, just in case.

Is there something I am missing? What could be the reason for it still showing those files?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you add files to .gitignore after 'git add' then you files will not be automatically removed from git.
2. Have you commited after manual removing large files from git?

Comment: yes, I re-added everything and commited.